# DIfferences between create-react-app on macos vs linux?

Tags: reactjs, macos, ubuntu

I'm getting a weird error from a project that I started from create-react-app on a macbook. When I cloned the project on my ubuntu drive, when I launch the app (npm start), it gives me this error. With some node & express errors.

```
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
at assertPath (path.js:28:11)
at Object.join (path.js:1236:7)
```

I tried reinstalling my dependencies, clearing npm cache, even reinstalling node.
I noticed some dependencies wouldn't work on linux.
The weird thing is, I have started other react projects on my linux machine and it works fine. The only one that gives me cryptic errors is the one I originally made on macos. Any clues as to what it could be ?

Comment: Have you tried removing both package-lock.json and node_modules, and doing a fresh npm install?

Comment: Yes I did ! Then I ran npm audit fix, for the vulnerabilities. The error is still there.

Comment: I just synced my code on both machines, I only get the TypeError on linux.

Comment: UPDATE : I fixed it by running react-script start instead of npm start, which makes no sense but ok.